# How to use Promise.timeout in play framework filter

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

We want to use Play framework to simulata another application. The requirement is to delay the response for example 5 seconds.

I want to do it in a filter, as it will apply to all actions. I want to use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout` to delay a response after the action returns. I am a newbie in Scala, I really don't know how to code with Scala, I always get a `Future[Future[Result]]` object.

Could someone tell me which method I should use and how?

**Edited**

My incorrect code with compile error

```
nextFilter(requestHeader).map {result=>
  play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(result, 5.seconds)
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your filter ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens, thanks! I haven't got workable code yet, I will add my incorrect code with compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

- `nextFilter` is a function which takes a `RequestHeader` and returns
  a `Future[Result]` (see [`Filter.apply`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Filter)).
- [`Promise.timeout`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$) returns a  `Future[A]`.

You combine them using the [`Future.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) function, which takes a function which turns `A` into `B` and returns a `Future[B]`, because in your case `Promise.timeout` returns a `Future[Result]`, you end up with `Future[Future[Result]]`.

We can solve this by using `flatMap` instead of `map`. `Future.flatMap` takes a function which turns `A` into `Future[B]`, that is just what `Promise.timeout` does, so you can use :

```
nextFilter(requestHeader).flatMap { result =>
  play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(result, 5.seconds)
}
```